# Under what conditions are the eigenvalues of a matrix finite?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have a square matrix $A$. Under what conditions on $A$ ensure that all eigenvalues of $A$ are finite?

Comment: What did you mean by **all eigenvalues of $A$ are finite**

Comment: Is $A$ a finite sized matrix with finite entries?

Comment: 'Finite' is sometimes used to mean non-zero...

Comment: @Hamou We can assume that $A$ is of dimension $N<\infty$. Under what conditions are all $N$ eigenvalues finite?

Comment: If you mean by finite $|\text{eigenvalue}|<\infty$, then in finite dimensional or not all eigenvalues are finite.

Comment: What do you mean by "in finite dimensional or not all eigenvalues are finite"?

Comment: @rogerG Can you give an example of a matrix that has a non-finite eigenvalue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe I've heard of an infinite eigenvalue before.  If the field of scalars involved is the field of real numbers or of complex numbers, then an eigenvalue is a real or complex number, and all of those are finite.  Only if there were such a thing as an infinite scalar could there be an infinite eigenvalue.  There are fields with elements that are in some sense infinite, but you'd need to explain which sorts of fields of scalars you're talking about before anyone's likely to say much.

Perhaps you have in mind that the set of eigenvalues might be unbounded.  If the eignevalues of an infinite matrix are $1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$, then there is no upper bound on the set of eigenvalues.  But each individual eigenvalue is still finite.  When the matrix has only finitely many entries, that sort of thing does not happen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the case where the matrix is actually a function, say $A(x) = \left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1\\
 0 & 1/x
 \end{array}
 \right]$. If $x\in[0,1]$, then the maximum eigenvalue is infinite, or perhaps just unbounded as $x\to0$. Does it make sense to define the matrix $A(0)$?

Comment: Perhaps in some contexts that could make sense, but I wouldn't write anything about that without explaining that that's what I meant by refering to an infinite eigenvalue.