# The limit of $2\frac{\sin\left(\frac{M\theta_{k}}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}(1+M)\theta_{k}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\theta_{k}}{2}\right)} $

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, fourier-transform

I have

$$\lambda_{k,N}=2\dfrac{\sin\Big(\dfrac{M\theta_{k}}{2}\Big) \cos\Big(\dfrac{1}{2}(1+M)\theta_{k}\Big)}{\sin\Big(\dfrac{\theta_{k}}{2}\Big)} $$

where $\theta_{k} \in [0, 2\pi]$, I can then let  $\theta_{k}=\dfrac{2\pi k}{N}$ for $k=0...N$,

I would like to find the limit of $\lambda_{k,N}$ when $N \to +\infty$ knowing that $M=M(N)$ and $\dfrac{M}{N}=0$ when $N \to +\infty$.

it would have been more interesting if I can compute the limit of $\lambda_{k,N}$ for any $k$ but it's not computable for some values of $\theta_{k}$.

Is it possible to find a closed form expression for the limit ?

Comment: I think you can use the fact that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\rightarrow 1, x\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Hey, just btw \lim_{a\to b} will give you a limit like $\lim_{a\to b}$. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the identity
\begin{equation}
\sin A\cos B=\frac{1}{2}[\sin(A+B)+\sin{(A-B)}]
\end{equation}
we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda_{kN}&=&\frac{\sin\left[\left(M+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta_k\right]-\sin\left(\frac{\theta_k}{2}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta_k}{2}\right)}\\
&=&\frac{\sin\left((2M+1)\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)}\\
&=&\frac{\sin\left((2M+1)\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
So for any fixed $k$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\lambda_{kN}=\lim_{n\to\infty}M(N)+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}M(N)
\end{equation}
provided the limit exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The $\lambda_{k,N}$ is actually an eigenvalue for a circulant adjacency matrix, and $M(N)$ is the size of the band that contain only the value 1. I have $M(N)=log(N)$, so when N goes to infinity, what does it mean to have an eigenvalue equal to infinity ?

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905574/under-what-conditions-are-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-finite

Comment: It could mean that the matrix is singular.

Comment: I have one question, $\dfrac{\pi k}{N}$ is not necessary zero when $N \to \infty $ but depends on the value of $k$. So, we can not use the $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \to 1$ for $x \to 0$.

Comment: You can use it for a fixed $k$, but not for an unfixed $k$ such as $k=N-1$, for example.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I believe it still works for $k=N-p$ for fixed $p$.

Comment: No, changed my mind again. It does not work for $k=N-p$. The identity needed is $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin Ax}{\sin x}=A$, but this does not follow for $x\to\pi$.

Comment: Yes, I would say that the limit does not exist but I am not sure.

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pi}\dfrac{\sin nx}{x}$ does not exist unless $n$ is an integer in which case the limit is $(-1)^{n-1}n$ which can be shown using L'Hopital's rule.